# How to edit content of CKEditor 5 from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a Chrome extension that replaces spelling errors text fields from webpages visited by the user.

The extension usually updates the text content from the text fields directly in DOM, but this does not work in CKEditor 5, as there is a MutationObserver that sees the DOM being changed by an outside script and undoes my changes.
I tried using the built-in CKeditor method setText(), but it requires having access to CKeditor "editor" object, which seems to be undefined in my extension's content script scope.

Do you know of any method to edit CKEDitor 5's content from my Chrome extension's content script ?

Comment: Please use  `world:"MAIN"` .

Comment: The links in the "This question already has answers here" section do not provide solutions that work with CKEditor 5. They only work in older versions of CKEditor.

Comment: Did you later find a solution for this issue? I am struggling with this as well.